# Dataframes.jl left join equivalent for arrays

Tags: julia

Is there such a package that can left join arrays, much like how dataframes.jl left join dataframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have complicated records as your arrays, it is probably best to just use DataFrames.jl. Put the arrays into dataframes and then join, then extract with an Array constructor.

If you know exactly what the logic of the left join is going to always be, you should be able to use a list comprehension efficiently instead. At the logic level of a general purpose left join, though, it's better to use dataframes.

```
julia> using DataFrames
julia> names = DataFrame(ID = [20, 40], Name = ["John Doe", "Jane Doe"])
2×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ ID │ Name     │
├─────┼────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ 20 │ John Doe │
│ 2   │ 40 │ Jane Doe │

julia> jobs = DataFrame(ID = [20, 40], Job = ["Lawyer", "Doctor"])
2×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ ID │ Job    │
├─────┼────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ 20 │ Lawyer │
│ 2   │ 40 │ Doctor │

julia> arr = Array(join(names, jobs, on = :ID, kind = :left))
2×3 Array{Any,2}:
20  "John Doe"  "Lawyer"
40  "Jane Doe"  "Doctor"
```

..or

```
julia> n = Array(names)
2×2 Array{Any,2}:
20  "John Doe"
40  "Jane Doe"

julia> j = Array(jobs)
2×2 Array{Any,2}:
20  "Lawyer"
40  "Doctor"

julia> [ [n[i,2], j[i,2]] for i in 1:size(n)[1] if n[i,1] == j[i,1]]
2-element Array{Array{String,1},1}:
String["John Doe", "Lawyer"]
String["Jane Doe", "Doctor"]
```